# What's the advantage of binding an alias to a local method?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working with the source code for [VirtualJoystick](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/virtualjoystick.js) and I'm confused about the method binding:

```
__bind = function(fn, me){return function(){return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
this._$onTouchStart = __bind(this._onTouchStart , this);
```

Next it creates an eventListener:

```
this._container.addEventListener( 'touchstart'  , this._$onTouchStart   , false );
```

which refers to a later-defined method:

```
VirtualJoystick.prototype._onTouchStart = function(event)
{
if( event.touches.length != 1 ) return;
event.preventDefault();
var x   = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX;
var y   = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY;
return this._onDown(x, y)
}
```

This seems convoluted to me. Why bind the alias before creating the eventListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because otherwise it would be called with a `this` equal to the global object (or to `null` in strict mode).

The same would happen if you did

```
var temp = this._onTouchStart;
temp();
```

In general any time you "alias" a method, i.e. don't call it directly as a method (with the appropriate object behind the dot), you lose the `this` context for it. Passing a method as a parameter does exactly this kind of aliasing, which is why it's necessary for `addEventListener`.

`__bind`, or its standard version [Function.prototype.bind](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5), gets around this, making sure that the function is called with the `this` pointer it expects. It creates a version of the function that is always called with the bound `this`, instead of the contextually-determined version.

Comment: After reading your answer, I found this article which seems to cover this particular issue in more detail:
http://bitstructures.com/2007/11/javascript-method-callbacks